# Calculating distance between two geoCodes in Cython

Tags: python, c, google-maps, geocoding, cython

My webservice currently retrieves geoCodes for addresses from the google API. When comparing the distance between the two geoCodes I have attempted to use the algorithm described here http://andrew.hedges.name/experiments/haversine/
unfortunately it returns inaccurate values.

There are two versions that I have are

```
cdef double M_PI = 3.141592653589793;
cdef double rads = (180/M_PI)

cdef double lon1 = a.geoCode[1];
cdef double lon2 = b.geoCode[1];

cdef double lat1 = a.geoCode[0];
cdef double lat2 = b.geoCode[0];

cdef double dlat = lon2 - lon1
cdef double dlon = lat2 - lat1

cdef double x  = (pow(sin(dlat/2),2)) + cos(lat1)*cos(lat2)*pow(sin(dlon/2),2);

cdef double c = 2.0 * atan2(sqrt(x), sqrt(1-x));

cdef double d = 6370.0 * c;

return d
```

An example of the values that are processed is

```
lat lon a 38.898556 -77.037852
lat lon b 38.897147 -77.043934
Difference in lat -0.00608199999999
Difference in long -0.001409
x 9.31324375062e-06
sqrt(x) 0.00305176076235
sqrt(1-x) 0.999995343367
atan2(sqrt(x),sqrt(1-x)) 1.5677445613
c 0.00610353099867
distance in kiloemters 38.8794924615
```

and

```
cdef double M_PI = 3.141592653589793;
cdef double rads = (180/M_PI)

cdef double lon1 = a.geoCode[1]*rads;
cdef double lon2 = b.geoCode[1]*rads;

cdef double lat1 = a.geoCode[0]*rads;
cdef double lat2 = b.geoCode[0]*rads;

cdef double dlat = lon2 - lon1
cdef double dlon = lat2 - lat1

cdef double x  = (pow(sin(dlat/2),2)) + cos(lat1)*cos(lat2)*pow(sin(dlon/2),2);

cdef double c = 2.0 * atan2(sqrt(x), sqrt(1-x));

cdef double d = 6370.0 * c;
return d
```

which processes

```
lat lon a 2228.72308795 -4413.94378235
lat lon b 2228.6423582 -4414.29225528
Difference in lat -0.348472930998
Difference in long -0.0807297533338
x 0.0301717372754
sqrt(x) 0.173700136083
sqrt(1-x) 0.984798589928
atan2(sqrt(x),sqrt(1-x)) 1.39621064139
c 0.349171370807
distance in kiloemters 2224.22163204
```

The problem is that the actual answer should be 0.549 km

I'm not sure what I have done differently than this formula

```
dlon = lon2 - lon1
dlat = lat2 - lat1
a = (sin(dlat/2))^2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * (sin(dlon/2))^2
c = 2 * atan2( sqrt(a), sqrt(1-a) )
d = R * c (where R is the radius of the Earth)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that radians conversion is inverted (180/π instead of π/180). The rest seems to be ok.

I use the following code in an application of mine, with good results (it is Objective-C, but similar):

```
// Credit:
// http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

double R = 6371000; // metres
double phi1 = lat1 * M_PI / 180.0;
double phi2 = lat2 * M_PI / 180.0;
double deltaphi = (lat2-lat1) * M_PI / 180.0;
double deltalambda = (long2-long1) * M_PI / 180.0;

double a = sin(deltaphi/2) * sin(deltaphi/2) +
    cos(phi1) * cos(phi2) *
    sin(deltalambda/2) * sin(deltalambda/2);
double c = 2 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1.0 - a));
double d = R * c;
return d;
```

My code does not use pow() but yours is correct in this respect because it avoids redundant sin() calculation.

Comment: Well now i feel like an idiot, thanks for noticing the rads. Seems to be closer with 0.687084042545